# 1st time sending PDF book of 48 pages created from InDesign to press

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

While I've been sending PDFs to press for years, I've never sent an annual 48 page booklet to press as a PDF. I've always sent InDesign package.

I guess the thing that makes me most nervous is the creep factor. I always thought that pre-press could only deal with creep from an InDesign file but now I'm told they can deal with it, if even if I supply PDF.

It would make my life so much easier as I have 54 RGB images!

Additionally I'm concerned about the flattening of some transparent graphics and the bleed for the edges that fall into the saddle stitched center.

Can anyone tell me more about making press ready PDF booklets for press?

Do they need individual pages and crop and bleed marks?

Comment: why do you have RGB images in something which is going to press? Shouldn't they be CMYK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is set up in reader spreads.... **Export as PDF/X-1a file, single pages, with bleeds and marks.**

If the file is set up in printer spreads.... **talk to your printer**. For books and manuals most print providers *really* want single pages so *they* can properly address creep and gutters. You need to verify that printer spreads will be okay.

Prepress departments have special software (Trapwize, Preps) which are used to format creep, spreads, bleeds, etc. This software works with PDFs. They honestly *will* handle it. It's their job and what they do.

All you need to be concerned about is your PDF/X-1a file contains all the proper content on the proper pages, in the proper order. And don't worry if you see [slight hairlines in your PDF/X-1a file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof).

You should also be provided with a proof before anything hits press.

You really should feel *better* about sending a PDF as opposed to an InDesign package. PDFs are *far* more "solid" for production and less can go wrong with a PDF/X-1a file. I'm *always* a bit apprehensive when asked for an InDesign Package. An ID package means images can move, text can reflow, a font can be missed -- none of that can happen with a PDF/X file.

Comment: Thanks very much Scott. I created the file in InDesign spreads. When I made a test run PDF with single pages, I see I have a lot of bleeds to fix. Still it's better than manually changing all my RGBs to CMYK. Is this the way the printing industry is going? One of my printers insists on PDFs.

Comment: I haven't sent anything but PDF/X files to print providers in at least 5 years. It's actually rare that I hear *anyone* request an InDesign package. Most commercial printers are using a PDF workflow these days specifically because it's much less prone to errors when compared to native files.

Comment: And if you see gutter images on both the left and right page bleeds in single pages, that how it *should* appear. You *should* see a little of the left part on the right page and a little of the right part on the left page. There is supposed to be a bit of an overlap. You might already know this, but it's worth pointing out just in case.

Comment: Well it's time I got with the flow! The rep that's done this job for the last 3 years probably should have told me. Thanks for the confidence. Exactly what I needed!

Comment: I didn't see your comment about the gutters until now. Hmmm... I don't get that. I'm not doing printer spreads. So I wouldn't want like page 2 bleeding on to page 48, (in a 52 page booklet.)

Comment: In the PDF/x File you *should* see the bleed of the right page when you view the left page. There *will* be some overlap. But if you look closely the overlap will stop at the trim marks. This is done so that the gutter content bleeds correctly when creep is factored. If you see gutter content stopping right at trim marks, things are not correct. And page 2 and page 48 should not be anywhere near each other.  So those two pages should not have common images in the bleed or anywhere.

Comment: Basically, (if using reader spreads) there shouldn't be *anything* specifically you need to alter in your InDesign file before generating the PDF/X file. The *only* exception would be to ensure your outside bleeds have enough content to bleed properly.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I can't believe how much time this is going to save me :)

Comment: No problem, Katie.  :) Glad I could help. If this has answered your question, please click the little check mark to the left of the answer.  Good luck! (And the speed is one reason designers prefer to send PDFs :) )

Comment: As an add-on, you might check whether your printer is X4-ready/certified. If so, it might be possible to send the files as PDF/X-4 (which keeps the images in RGB). However, it requires prepress skills on the printer's side, therefore the X4 certification). If you can not evaluate this, stay with PDF/X-1a, which does not leave anything to interpretation.