# Overlapping elements creating artifacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, visual-artifacts

I am creating a PDF for printing, and I got some weird artifacts on places where elements with the same color overlap.
My workflow is from Illustrator to InDesign to PDF, and to be honest I dont know where the problem comes from.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean :

[image]
Here you can see it on the brownish-beige part

Here is another one where you can see that they are really overlapping 
The lower beige part is on top of the upper one, whose green outlines you can see

[image]

The weird thing is, it depends on the actual Zoom level whether or not you see the line. How can I get rid of this? I am scared this will be visible on the print later on...

INSERT: These screenshots are from Illustrator CC2017.1.0 on Mac. The problem is visible also in InDesign, Acrobat and Adobe reader. The problematic shapes are only simple paths - one triangle and one half circle.

Comment: It's completely impossible to see anything from just a thin line from a screen shot. Please edit your post to include more of the graphics so we can see what type of shapes and objects we’re dealing with and how they overlap. If it depends on the zoom level, there's a good chance it's a screen artefact that won't show up when printing, but at the very least we need to see what's going on in order to be able to give a reasonably educated guess.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tought you were able to see it on the left and right , ill add some images

Comment: Ah, that’s much better—now it’s clear what’s intentional and what’s artefact. That definitely looks like screen artefacting to me. If you want to be entirely sure, you can always combine the two beige shapes into a compound shape. If the artefacts remain after that, then there’s something not right.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will try that one out :)

Comment: Where your screenshots are taken from? Illustrator, InDesign, Acrobat ,Adobe PDF reader or from something else? Which of these is the earliest where the error is visible?

Comment: This is illustator but its visible in every step

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem otherwise than by adding a stroke. Are your shapes plain drawings or are they results from complex path operations? Are there rasterized parts? What is your Illustrator version?

Comment: They are simple paths , ones a half-circle and the other a triangle, I am using Illustator CC 2017.1.0 on a Mac

Comment: Maybe you can insert a link to a problematic ai file to make possible for other CC2017 users to verify is it in your graphic system or in CC2017. When waiting the result, try to combine the shapes of the same colour as a workaround. You can for example unite them in the pathfinder panel.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof

Comment: Possible duplicate [embossed svg](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060). Solution: [Is there a reason Hillary Clinton's logo has hidden notches?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there unwanted white lines appearing in a PDF print proof?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof)

Answer (score 1):

If it Starts from Illustrator given it is a vector file. Can you check if the shape that have same color separated from each other? If Yes Merge them with Path Finder or Shape Builder Tool to eliminate that line.

A. Select the upper and lower path; then Pathfinder>Unite
[image]

B. Select the upper and lower path; Shift+M then Click and Drag to the two Separated Shapes
[image]

If it is not separated in vector or Ai format; based on my experience I guess the problem is the exporting from InDesign to PDF. Check your PDF Settings maybe it is low PDF type that it it chop some files. But surprisingly it is the only shape affected and the others are Okay. :-)