# Illustrator overprint problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, overprint

I have some big trouble with overprinting images in the AI. Files and images in them, that I have, are already been printed, and there was no trouble with them, overprint worked well and all 100% black in the images was overprinted. But now I'm working with files on the other computer and when I save the PDF, in output preview I see white gaps.

The images are complex logos, so I can't just hit Multiply and forget about it, and they are also on transparent backgrounds, so Multiply in the image itself also don't work. I tried other things that I found on the internet, but they didn't work, I still have gaps and a deadline.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is a specific options on Save window, that I missed, but they was chosen on the other computer? Can't check it on that computer thou, because it doesn't exist anymore.

Update: I don't have hairlines! Typography doesn't accept my file, because not all my black is overprinted, it's a trapping problem. i need to make this images to overprint, not a knockout colors under it(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there unwanted white lines appearing in a PDF print proof?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof)

Comment: It's definetely not my issue(

Comment: Put *Illustrator White gaps* at the the search field, there are several answers with this topic

Comment: Nothing there. It's not the same gaps, gaps itself are not even the problem, not working overprint is( Gaps in my issue is an indicator in Acrobat Pro, that my black are not in overprint mode. Print service doesn't accept such files

Comment: I'm having a difficult time even understanding the issue. A sample image would help.

Comment: please [edit] your question to make it more clear, otherwise it might end up being closed.