# How to deal with PDF file containing thin lines/partitioned in boxes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production

We are a publisher. Customers often send us advertisements ready for printing.

Sometimes when these advertisements are in PDF file format the whole advertisement or parts of it are partitioned in boxes, so you see e.g. lines inside images or a „border“ around text.

Here are two different examples:

[image: example1][image: example2]

These are screenshots of the PDF files. As you can imagine these lines shouldn't be there.

If I zoom in or out the lines sometimes disappear but they never change width. I read a lot about it but I still don't really understand it:

1. How is it called? I found stitching, flattening, light leaks and flattened transparency.
2. It it really safe to print? If I e.g. print this with my printer at home these lines are visible. Is it sure they won't be visible when they come from the printery? Why? Is it the resolution of the printer? If yes, where's the limit that decides between visible and not visible?
3. If I export the PDF file to an image format like TIFF or JPG the lines are visible there, too. If I'd print it like this the lines definitely would be visible after printing no matter what printer, won't they?
4. Is this a fault on the customers side or should I be able to deal with that? What can I do to get rid of these lines? Or, what can I tell the customer to do?

Comment: These are called conflation artifacts. It's caused by flattening transparency when exporting as PDF.  It shouldn't really cause a problem with printing because it's an -on screen phenomenon, however perhaps request a proof before going to print for peace of mind.  Most printers these days prefer PDFs exported with the newer PDF/X-4 standard, which avoids the problem.

Comment: See possible duplicate question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38598/why-are-there-unwanted-white-lines-appearing-in-a-pdf-print-proof - although this is for Illustrator, but the same issue.